# MongoDB Compass error creating SSH Tunnel: connect EADDRINUSEt, after setting username / password on database, AWS Linux 2 (EC2)

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongodb-compass, amazon-linux-2

I have setup my mongodb on AWS Linux 2 EC2 instance.

I have associated inbound rule as - SSH | TCP | 22 |  to the instance.

I was able to SSH into it through MongoDB Compass by using following settings:

[image]

However as soon as I added a username password to my database using following method:

```
use my_database

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "some_user",
    pwd: "some_password",
    roles: [{ role: "readWrite", db: "my_database" }]
  }
)
```

And tried to access it using following parameters:

[image]

I got following error:

```
Error creating SSH Tunnel: connect EADDRINUSE some_ip:22 - Local (0.0.0.0:29353)
```

Here is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file content:

```
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none


# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
PermitEmptyPasswords no
#PasswordAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
#UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect
```

Am I missing anything over here?

Comment: Hi did you solve this? Have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was running in to the exact same issue when trying to connect through an SSH tunnel. I have found a quirky solution for this issue.

I solved it by installing [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com/). Once opened create a new connection by clicking on `Connect` -> `New Connection`.

Once opened set up your connection, save it, and you should be able to connect successfully.

When this is complete do the following:

1. Click on `Connect` once again.
2. Right-click the saved connection and select `Edit...`.
3. At the bottom left there is an option named `To URI...` to export the Connection String.
4. And Finally select the option `Include Passwords` and copy the Connection String.

That's it! You can now paste it in MongoDB Compass and you should be good to go.